# Bearear token didn't set when HTTP calls made @azure/angular

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I have implemented the Azure AD in one of my project. After login I have tried to make an Http calls to the web api which is the protected ones.
Implemented the steps mentioned in the docs. But once I make an http call getting 401 unauthorized.
Tried debugging in a networks tab in devtools. The Authorization is not set in the request header.
As per the docs the msal interceptor will set the token. But in my case the token is not set by msal.
The token are available in localstorage.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code

Comment: Can you provide your MSAL interceptor configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Better off you shoud try using keycloak to manager access token between angular app client and AD
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUpIGxEDz4k